# Unable to place an image using Javascript for a random image generator code

Tags: javascript, image

[image of a mole to be placed randomly in the squares created][1
**
I am trying to code the game called 'Whack-a-mole'. I created h1 and div elements to be placed on screen using **javascript** . Then I wanted to place an image inside the squares to appear randomly, but it does not appear in the squares. Could you please help me with where I went wrong ?
Thank You

. I add

```js
// MY CODE

// const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
// h1.textContent = 'Your Score: ';
// h1.id = 'score';
// document.body.append(h1);

// const time = document.createElement('h1');
// time.textContent = 'Time Left: ';
// time.id = 'time';
// document.body.append(time);

// const grid = document.createElement('div');
// grid.className = 'grid';
// document.body.append(grid);



// for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
//     let square = document.createElement('img');
//     square.className = 'square';
//     square.id = ('data-id', i+1);
//     grid.append(square);
// };

// const result = document.querySelector('#score');
// const left = document.querySelector('#time');
// const boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
// const images = document.querySelector('.mole');

// function randomMole() {
//     boxes.forEach(box => {
//         box.classList.remove('images');
//     });

//     let randomSquare = boxes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)];
//     randomSquare.classList.add('images');
// };
// randomMole();
















 



// Ania code

const squares = document.querySelectorAll('.square')
const mole = document.querySelector('.mole')
const timeLeft = document.querySelector('#time-left')
const score = document.querySelector('#score')

let result = 0
let hitPosition
let currentTime = 60
let timerId = null

function randomSquare() {
  squares.forEach(square => {
    square.classList.remove('mole')
  })

  let randomSquare = squares[Math.floor(Math.random() * 9)]
  randomSquare.classList.add('mole')

  hitPosition = randomSquare.id
}
randomSquare();

squares.forEach(square => {
  square.addEventListener('mousedown', () => {
    if (square.id == hitPosition) {
      result++
      score.textContent = result
      hitPosition = null
    }
  })
})

function moveMole() {
  timerId = setInterval(randomSquare, 500)
}

moveMole()

function countDown() {
 currentTime--
 timeLeft.textContent = currentTime

 if (currentTime == 0) {
   clearInterval(countDownTimerId)
   clearInterval(timerId)
   alert('GAME OVER! Your final score is ' + result)
 }

}

let countDownTimerId = setInterval(countDown, 1000)
```

```css
.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .square {
    width: 135px;
    height: 135px;
    border: solid rgb(11, 8, 8) 1px;
  }
  .mole {
    background-image: url('images/mole.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
 <h2>Your score:</h2>
    <h2 id="score">0</h2>
  
    <h2>Time Left:</h2>
    <h2 id="time-left">60</h2>
 
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="square" id="1"></div>
      <div class="square" id="2"></div>
      <div class="square" id="3"></div>
      <div class="square" id="4"></div>
      <div class="square" id="5"></div>
      <div class="square" id="6"></div>
      <div class="square" id="7"></div>
      <div class="square" id="8"></div>
      <div class="square" id="9"></div>
    </div>
      
    <script src="Ania JS/Ania game 3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**

Comment: Why is most of your html commented out?

Comment: Hello Lee, I was trying to place everything in html using Javascript. So I commented it. Also now, I edited the code by using Ania Kubow's code (develper and tutor on Youtube). Hers is working not mine, why? Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you need the `.mole` class to display the image. Here's a a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for your code.

Play with it by forking [this stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-fbbdwr?file=index.js).

Or [play the game](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-duk2bu?file=index.js) itself

```js
document.addEventListener(`click`, evt => 
  evt.target.id === `redo` && randomMole());

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  `beforeend`, `<div class="grid">${
    [...Array(8)].map((_, i) => `<img class="square" data-id=${i}>`)
      .join(``) }</div>`);

document.querySelector(`#redo`).click();

function randomMole() {
    const mole = document.querySelector(`.mole`);
    mole && mole.classList.remove('mole');
    document.querySelectorAll('.square')[Math.floor(Math.random() * 8)]
      .classList.add(`mole`);
};
```

```css
.grid {
    width: 600px;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.square {
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border: solid rgb(11, 8, 8) 1px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
.mole {
  background-image: url('//cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2012/05/02/17/24/ground-45742_960_720.png');
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<p><button id="redo">random mole position</button></p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Kooilinc. Picture on the screen looks cool. Just one or two jquery commands I haven't used. Appreciate your reply

Comment: You're welcome ;) There is not a shred of *jquery* in my answer (nor in the linked stackblitz project), what do you mean?

Comment: I haven't used ...Array & join commands yet, but he code is simple. I put the code of another developer, "Ania Kubow", her's works for me when using vscode but mine doesn't. Please tell me where I went wrong. Also, Thanks a lot for your reply.

Comment: Like I said: you're using the wrong class, it should be `.mole` - that's what's containing the image (as a background image).

Comment: THanks a lot Kooilnc. The names of css file and js file didn't match & when I corrected it, it's working. I misunderstood your comment. Sorry & Thanks